# Why is my camera facing backwards at the start of my zoom?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a basic function to move my camera as it scrolls but it starts facing backwards and as soon as I do the first scroll it flips around the right way and works as intended. (I'm also very new to coding)

NOTE : there is much more code for other functions and stuffs that I have left out.

````
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

//Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

//Renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: document.querySelector('#bg'),

});

renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
camera.position.setZ(30);


renderer.render( scene, camera );

//Scrolling to move
function moveCamera(){
  const t = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
 

  camera.position.z = t * -0.01;
  camera.position.x = t * -0.0002;
  camera.rotation.y = t * -0.0002;
}

document.body.onscroll = moveCamera```
````

Answer (score 0):

I figured it using a simple method :

console.log(camera.position.z) to see where the camera was at each scroll.

It was dipping into the negatives so I wrote a simple if statement to set it back to 0.1 if it ever gets < 0.1

```
if(camera.position.z < 0.1){
  camera.position.z = 0.1
}
```